# How to show a panel if a node is selected in a treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tree view structured like this

```
 Node0
   -Node1
      -Node11
      -Node12
   -Node2
```

And i have two panels: panel11 & panel12. I want to show panel11 if Node11 is selected & if Node12 is selected i want to show panel12. How can i do that in my WF in C#?

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward to me. Where are you having problems?

Comment: private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

{
            
           if(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text=="Node11")

           {

               panel1l.Visible = true;

           }

}

It's giving me NullReference exception was unhandled error.

Comment: some of your references are null. Check if you initialize your `panel11` correctly. Btw. is it a typo or is your object really named `panel1l` ?

Comment: Sorry i wrote that wrong it's panel11.

Answer (score 3):

Write a handler for the `AfterSelect` event on the treeview, where you can do whatever you have to do to handle the node that the user selected.

```
 private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.node == nodePanel11)
    {
       Panel11.Visible = true;   // This presumes that the panel already exists 
                                 // and is invisible
       Panel12.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (e.node == nodePanel12)
    {
        Panel12.Visible = true;
        Panel11.Visible = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you give me a example?